# Why does this If Statement stop code execution?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new at Python & I do not understand why my `if` statement is not working as expected.

My `for` loop uses a function to list filenames and content types

```
def listContentType(files):

   contentType = "text/xml"

   for filename in files:
       if '.html' in filename :
            contentType = 'text/html"

       # do something
       print(contentType)
```

But, when `if` Statement returns `true`, `print` never prints 'text/html'.

Do you know why?

Comment: Print `files` to see if it contains what you expect it to

Comment: FYI, once you do encounter '.html' in a filename, your code will only print 'text/html' because it's never changed to anything else.

Comment: i only have xml and html files in `files` and i want it to print `text/html` when any html file is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You used two different types of quotation marks to define `contentType`.

Try this:

```
def listContentType(files):



   for filename in files:
       contentType = "text/xml"

       if '.html' in filename :
            contentType = 'text/html'
       print(contentType)
```

Comment: Thank you @Steven, what if i want to print `text/xml` and `text/html` assuming i have xml and html files in `files`?

Comment: Ok, I edited the code so that `contentType` is automatically set to `text/xml` on each iteration.